# What is the correct selector string to get the particular elements I want in HTML structured like this?

Tags: javascript, html, css-selectors

```
<body><form>

<fieldset>
 <legend>Current Node Information</legend>
    <label>Node Name: <input type="text" id="nodeNameField"></label><br>
    <label>Node Type: <input type="text" id="nodeTypeField"></label><br>
    <label>Node Value: <input type="text" id="nodeValueField"></label><br>
    <label>Child Element Count: <input type="text" id="childElementCountField"></label>
</fieldset>

<fieldset id="navFieldset">
 <legend>Movement Controls</legend>
 <input type="button" value="Parent" data-prop="parentNode" id="parentBtn">
 <input type="button" value="First Child" data-prop="firstChild" id="firstChildBtn">
 <input type="button" value="Reset to Root" data-prop="root" id="rootBtn">
</fieldset>
</form></body>
```

It works fine with the selector (String parameter inside querySelectorAll function)

```
window.onload = function () {
    nodeMove.currentElement = document.documentElement;

    var elements = document.querySelectorAll("fieldset#navFieldset input");  
    for (var i = 0, len = elements.length; i < len; i++)  {
        elements[i].onclick = function () { nodeMove(this) };
    }
    update(nodeMove.currentElement);
}
```

Below is the list of the selectors I have tried so far.

```
#navFieldset input    // this works fine
legend > input        // ERROR
#navFieldset > input  // this works fine
fieldset > input      // this works fine
fieldset#navFieldset  // ERROR
```

I need to select all the buttons within the fieldset.
I want to know in the cases which are shown as `this woks fine`, is there any difference bw those particular selectors. Furthermore, why are the cases shown as `ERROR` wrong. I wish to know the reasons. I am reading CSS Selectors from this [resource](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#id-selectors).

Comment: @Artjom B: I need to select all the buttons with the fieldset. You could have easily make it out from the String parameter within querySelectorAll() function.

Comment: Yes, I could've if it was correctly indented so that the `//working` and `//not working` comments were visible. Now that I know that, what is the problem? There are selectors that work, so what is the question exactly?

Comment: @Artjom B: If in case, I show them as uncommented, people might assume it to be in flow of the program.

Comment: The difference should be pretty obvious when you have all these selectors to compare side-by-side. For example, what makes you think `fieldset#navFieldset` would select your inputs if all your other selectors end with `input`?

Comment: "I am reading CSS Selectors from this resource." And what have you learned from reading it? It's no use telling us you've read something if you're not even going to comment on it.

Comment: @BoltClock: Thank you for telling me this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Working selectors

Yes, those selectors are all different, but select the correct thing. This redundancy/flexibility is needed for CSS selectors for when slightly different markup comes along.

### Non-working selectors

`legend > input` doesn't work, because `legend` is not a parent of `input`. Those are siblings. You can use `legend ~ input`.

`fieldset#navFieldset` selects the `fieldset`, but you seem to be interested in the `input` children. You can use the child selector `>`: `fieldset#navFieldset > input` in the same way you use the descendend selector  (space): `fieldset#navFieldset input`.

Comment: "You can use fieldset#navFieldset > input." ... or any of the other selectors that have already been shown to work.

Comment: What a fool am i to assume legend to be the parent of input